# Algebraic limit theorem with absolute value

Tags: real-analysis

If I assume $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$, then does it follow that $\lim|x_n-y_n|\rightarrow |x-y|$?

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Comment: Using triangle ineq., $|x_n-y_n|=|x_n-x+x-y_n|\leq|x_n-x|+|x-y_n|$.

Comment: What can you say about $||x_n - y_n| - |x-y||$?

Comment: Ah, $||x_n - y_n| - |x-y||\leq |x_n - y_n - x+y| <\epsilon$.